# Build Container-Optimized OS - Swap SSH implementation

Tags: containers, google-compute-engine

**TL;DR:**
I'm trying to modify sshd_conf and add a binary to container-optimized OS image. Is it madness to modify `chromeos-base-2.ebuild`?

**Background**
I'm (trying) to build my own container optimized OS image using instructions from https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/building-from-open-source. My goal is to swap our the SSH authentication parts.

To do this I need to do two actions:

1. Modify sshd_config
2. Include an additional binary (that is executable)

And I'm trying to do this in a container-optimized os friendly way.

My thinking is that I modify `src/overlays/overlay-lakitu/chromeos-base/chromeos-base/chromeos-base-2.ebuild` to include my binary:

```
insinto /usr/sbin
doins "${FILESDIR}"/sshauth
fperms 700 /usr/sbin/sshauth
```

And then change `src/overlays/overlay-lakitu/chromeos-base/chromeos-base/files/sshd_config` to include:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  /dev/null
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/sbin/sshauth
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser root
```

I then run `emerge-lakitu chromeos-base` to re-build the package I just modified. I then run `./build_image --board=lakitu base` and use that as an image on GCE.

Questions:

1. Is this madness?
2. My binary is included in the produced image, but the sshd_config I changed is overwritten with the default one.

My initial way was to use packer to simply change the config and add the binary, but the binary needs to be executable. I guess I could place the binary in `/var/lib/cloud` but that feels a bit dirty.

Comment: Turns out  my dirty way doesn't work well either, the sshd_config is reset everytime the instance restarts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be best to simply run your own sshd agent in a container with your custom config.
There is a good example here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/ that I tested and works on COS as well.

Make sure to open the port your server is listening using iptables.

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport <port> -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport <port> -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

You could also stop the built-in sshd service and reuse port 22 from host itself if you want.

Hope this helps.

Edit:
Regarding:

> My binary is included in the produced image, but the sshd_config I changed is overwritten with the default one.

Make sure you have incremented the ebuild revision. i.e.
rename `chromeos-base-2-r25.ebuild` symlink to  `chromeos-base-2-r26.ebuild`. This is needed make sure that your changes to the package are picked up. Otherwise a pre-built package from cache is used.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone coming here via Google, besides running sshd in a container you can also use cloud-init to setup your sshd_config. The workflow then is:

1. Disable SSHd (preferbly in bootcommand)
2. Download your new SSHD config via wget (from GCS, or similar)
3. Restart your SSHd

In the words of Aditya:

> I would highly recommend to just use the containerized ssh server
>   approach (and you can disable the host sshd if you want).
>   Alternatively, you could do the modifications to sshd_config from your
>   cloud-config. That way, even if the changes under /etc/ are not
>   persistent, they will simply get re-applied on every boot.

TL;DR: Try not to roll your own cos image, you end up loosing the fast-pace development (and need to support it yourself)